# Laravel login not working on production with white page showing request data

Tags: php, laravel, docker, production

I suddenly have this weird thing on the live version of my project/website. I didn’t work on it for a few weeks and when I started again yesterday I suddenly had this error/fault. It’s really weird and I have no clue, but I’m just gonna try to explain it.

When I try to login to the website, with the correct credentials, I get a white page with a sort of get request. It shows the _token, email and password in plain text. This page is visible for a second or so before it redirects and brings me back to the login page, without logging me in.

[screenshot of the white page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv8s7.jpg)

This is the basic problem. But here are some things that make it confusing and weird.

- On my own machine it works just fine. I’m using docker, so my dev and production setups are 99% the same. Only differences are the ports of the containers.
- It was working a few weeks ago, and now, without me changing a thing, this happens.
- And maybe the weirdest thing: when I bring down the containers and then bring them back up (docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d —build) it works. I can login and everything. But after some (unknown) time it stops working and I get this again.

There are no errors or any feedback. It just doesn’t work and shows that white page for a split second. The request does seem to be validated though. When I enter wrong credentials the same thing occurs, but I get the validation message in the form, as expected.

I have absolutely no idea where this might even remotely come from. So if anyone has any clue for a direction, just ask me for the info and I’ll provide it.

I’m on Laravel 8.

---

UPDATE / FIX
==============

Okay now that it hasn't failed in a week I'm fairly confident in saying that I fixed it. So what I did to fix it is (mostly based on this answer):

- Found out what container/image had the issue. Turned out to be php-fpm.
- In the Dockerfile for this container I added the commands from this answer.
- Added the local IP (127.0.0.1) on the port bindings for all containers not publicly available.
- Rebooted my server. Before I did this the fixes seemed to work, but it just took longer for the issue to return. After reboot it hasn't failed so far.

I think those were all the changes I did.

Comment: Maybe its because of HTTPS redirect on your production server?

Comment: I don’t have https setup, it’s just plain old http

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code from your login controller etc. I would just try to manually debug on your live system with dd calls.

Comment: Yeah I tried to add a dd() in the AuthenticatesUser class thingy. I got the same page with beneath that request string the things I dumped, so I think I was sorta in the right spot, or a bit close at least. I will try some more and see if I can figure out the origin. The hard thing is that it’s only on production, so any solution or possibility I think of also comes with the thought “but why does it work on my dev machine. That doesn’t make sense”. But I guess code doesn’t always make sense.

Comment: Maybe you left an `echo(http_build_query(request()->all()))` somewhere. It looks similar to what i get whenever i `dump($something)` before redirecting to another page. Check the response's source code with your browser

Comment: Given no HTTPS, perhaps there is a proxy or ISP intercepting the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Debug.

I had the same issue for almost three days. It turned out to be a cryptocurrency miner script which later introduces a malware, 'kinsing'.

For anyone using laravel for an API, the 'symptom' for me was returning `Content-Type` header as `text/html` as opposed to `application/json` in the responses for all my post requests. This, like the login, would work okay for some time. Also all the responses returned success `200` status code irrespective of what I had  in my codebase.

To confirm that this is indeed the same issue for you:

- RUN: `$ top`    // to check the CPU processes.

You'll notice a suspicious process named `kdevtmpfsi` or `Kinsing` using obnoxiously high amounts of CPU. Mine was at 400%.

You may have to check for a while as it sometimes disappears.
If you find the culprit the great, now you know the problem and might want to  [see issue thread](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/217) .

### Summary of what worked for me.

As suggested in the issue thread above, here's the solution that worked for me.

1. Found all instances of the associated files.

   - `find / -iname kdevtmpfsi`
   - `find / -iname kinsing`
2. Created and run a script to remove and replace all instances of the files, make them non-executable, and only allow root and one `other user` to edit them. (You can also run the commands directly in your terminal, from within the 'infected' container). On my server the files were in `/var/tmp/kinsing` `/tmp/kinsing` and `/tmp/kdevtmpfsi`.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    rm -rf /var/tmp/kinsing /tmp/kinsing /tmp/kdevtmpfsi && touch /tmp/kdevtmpfsi && 
    touch /var/tmp/kinsing && touch /tmp/kinsing
    echo "everything is good here" > /tmp/kdevtmpfsi
    echo "everything is good here" > /var/tmp/kinsing
    echo "everything is good here" > /tmp/kinsing
    chmod go-rwx /var/tmp
    chmod 1777 /tmp
    touch /etc/cron.allow
    echo "root" > /etc/cron.allow
    echo "{other uer}" >> /etc/cron.allow
    cat /tmp/kdevtmpfsi && cat /var/tmp/kinsing && cat /tmp/kinsing
   ```

**remember to make the script executable if you go the script way**

3. Updated all my docker images. (Deleted old ones then pulled new ones). I want to assume you already know how to do this.
4. Closed all my ports from the public and only exposed the webserver ports. To prevent future attacks. So the `ports` section of your laravel app service and db service would be something like this:

   **laravel app service**

   ```
   ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
      - "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"
   ```

   **db service**

   ```
   ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
   ```

   This basically binds the ports to connections only from the host since `127.0.0.1` is only accessible via your machine/server. Port mappings without the localhost binding map the ports to every interface on your machine/server. This is less than desirable if you have a public IP address, or your machine has an IP on a large network and is likely how the attackers accessed your server. Find more on port binding [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports).

**Of course, this depends on the services you want publicly available. The point is not to give the public what they don't need.**

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the issue. Searching for those files gives me this:
[link](https://i.imgur.com/fPRAIey.png)
I don't think I can rely on this hash in the paths and be able to use those in your script. Do you have any idea how I can use these paths and somehow fix the issue, and prevent it from happening again after I rebuild the image? 
I don't know what image has the problem. If I knew that I might be able to use your script, find the files inside of the container and run the script there somehow. But this is all pretty advanced stuff compared to my experiences so far

Comment: The files are located in the overlay2 directory which you shouldn't directly manipulate. A way to remove those files is by completely removing the image along with its layers.

A container's layer directory is typically contained  at `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<containerID>/`

You could run a `docker ps` to list your  `container IDs` along with their associated images. From the [Link](https://i.imgur.com/fPRAIey.png) you shared the container ID/hash is the same so you should be able to see the image you need to remove frome there.

Comment: To remove an image along with its layers run `docker rm -f  imageID`

Comment: For security, so that it never happens again,  make sure you close all publicly exposed ports and only expose those that you need to be accessible publicly. This is usually the webserver port. Refer to answer point 4 on how to do this.

Comment: Is the IP important in point 4? I have similar port mappings, only without the IP adddress.
I found the container that was causing the issue for my project. That was the only container (of this project) where I could find those files within the container. In my case this was my php container running php7.4-fpm from a Dockerfile. To this Dockerfile I added the commands of your script. Now it's basically wait, see and hope that this was sufficient (for now) and the processes don't return

Comment: That's actually a better approach.  As for the IP in point 4, it is a security measure. It basically binds the ports to connections only from the host since `127.0.0.1` is only accessible via your machine.
Your current mappings, without the localhost binding, maps the port to every interface on your machine. This is less than desirable if you have a public IP address, or your machine has an IP on a large network. 
 Find [more in the docs here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)